# setting a Map type field in a bean (which will contain other beans), using XML

Tags: java, spring

so here's my question -

lets say i have couple of services, Service_A, Service_B, etc..(all extends Service class)

every service is a bean, and has a function getKey() that returns the key of the service - of type ServiceKey.

now, i want to define a new bean - ServiceManager. which will have a memeber:

```
HashMap<ServiceKey,Service> serviceMap.
```

i wanted to ask, if there a way to inject all the existing Service types bean to this Map memeber using a bean definition in XML?

something like this doesnt help me:

```
<bean id="serviceManager" class="ServiceManager">
    <property name="serviceMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="A" value="service_a"/>
            <entry key="B" value="service_a"/>
            <entry key="C" value="service_c"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

i dont want it hard coded, i wonder if there's a way to take each existing Service class, and define it like this that the map will be field using the getKey() function from each service

getKey(),Service

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why xml? Why not @Autowired?

Comment: using XML in the workplace

Comment: This is easier to do with annotations. Is annotations support disabled in the project?

Comment: i can go with Autowired. prefer an XML solution if such exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to specify a custom key when injecting all beans of a specific type to a Map. [Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config) say:

> Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is
>   String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type,
>   and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names

So a solution is to have a `Collection<Service> services` in `ServiceManager` and autowire all `Service` beans. Then have an `afterPropertiesSet()` which will convert the collection to a Map.

Example using only xml:

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="serviceManager" class="com.test.ServiceManager" autowire="byType" />

    <bean class="com.test.Service1"></bean>
    <bean class="com.test.Service2"></bean>

</beans>
```

TestApp

```
package com.test;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");
        ServiceManager serviceManager = context.getBean(ServiceManager.class);
        System.out.println(serviceManager.getServiceMap());
    }
}
```

ServiceManager

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

public class ServiceManager implements InitializingBean {

    private Collection<Service> services;

    HashMap<ServiceKey, Service> serviceMap = new HashMap<ServiceKey, Service>();

    public Collection<Service> getServices() {
        return services;
    }

    public void setServices(Collection<Service> services) {
        this.services = services;
    }

    public HashMap<ServiceKey, Service> getServiceMap() {
        return serviceMap;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        for (Service service : services) {
            serviceMap.put(service.getKey(), service);
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
package com.test;

public interface Service {

    ServiceKey getKey();
}
```

ServiceKey

```
package com.test;

public class ServiceKey {

    private String key;

    public ServiceKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key;
    }

}
```

Service1

```
package com.test;

public class Service1 implements Service {

    public ServiceKey getKey() {
        return new ServiceKey("one");
    }

}
```

Service2

```
package com.test;

public class Service2 implements Service {

    public ServiceKey getKey() {
        return new ServiceKey("two");
    }
}
```

Comment: first of, thanks for the answer! second, since the xml defintion of serviceManager is pretty much empyty, its the "autowire="byType"" that does the work?  P.S - any point for that "afterPropertiesSet()" function?

Comment: Yes, I added some explanations.

Comment: so i need to define an Init method which will call "afterPropertiesSet()", or am i missing something?

Comment: No, I've made ServiceManager implement the org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean. So Spring will call it automatically. You could do it with an init method too. Also with @PostConstruct.

Comment: oh i see. so yeah, that will work. but i wonder if theres no way to inject to a map using a function for a key, and not inject to a collection.

Comment: Not that I know of. There is injection to a map, but the key will be the spring bean id, which is not what you want.

Comment: From the documentation: "Even typed Maps can be autowired as long as the expected key type is String. The Map values will contain all beans of the expected type, and the keys will contain the corresponding bean names"